# How to create right query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying write a query:

`SELECT id FROM users WHERE status = 3`

But if this sample returns an empty response, then I need instead to select the id where `status = 4`, and if it returns empty again, where `status = 5`.

How can I write a single query to solve this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a subquery in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Is this column id unique? If also the result for status = 5 is empty, do you need to search for results for status = 6?

Comment: status 5 never can be empty, at least one user with status 5 is excist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the case statement in the where clause:

```
select id 
from users
where status = case when status = 3 and id is null then 4
                    when status = 4 and id is null then 5
               else 3
               end
```

Let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 4):

I think you simply want:

```
SELECT id
FROM users 
WHERE status >= 3
ORDER BY status asc
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want multiple users:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM users u
WHERE u.status = (SELECT MIN(u2.status)
                  FROM users u2
                  WHERE u2.status >= 3
                 );
```

If you have a fixed list you want to test, you can also use:

```
select u.id
from users u
where u.status = 3
union all
select u.id
from users u
where u.status = 4 and
      not exists (select 1 from users u2 where u2.status in (3))
union all
select u.id
from users u
where u.status = 5 and
      not exists (select 1 from users u2 where u2.status in (3, 4));
```

Comment: unfortunately, I need get all users with this status , nt only one

Answer (score 3):

You can use OR condition or use IN operator

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE status = 3 or status = 3 or status = 5
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE status IN (3,4,5)
```

Comment: Sounds wierd but 9 out off the 10 times you can better rewrite this to `UNION ALL` kind of queries like `SELECT id FROM users WHERE status = 3 UNION ... status = 4 ...UNION ... status = 5`  Oracle's database does this rewite automatic for most `OR` or `IN()` queries. Or because these are incrementing values your better off using `status BETWEEN 3 AND 5` instead and force a range scan.

Comment: may be OP start to learn query, i want to provide an option for him, may be I will delete answer soon

Comment: THisq query will return status 5 even if status 3 exist.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table look like this:

```
+----+--------+
| id | status |
+----+--------+
|  1 |      3 |
|  1 |      4 |
|  1 |      5 |
|  3 |      3 |
|  3 |      4 |
|  4 |      4 |
|  4 |      5 |
|  5 |      5 |
+----+--------+
```

And based on your condition where you want to see the lowest status first for each id, you can use `MIN()` operator.
So, from your original query:

```
SELECT id,MIN(status) FROM users GROUP BY id;
```

Then you'll get a result like this:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | MIN(status) |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |      3      |
|  3 |      3      |
|  4 |      4      |
|  5 |      5      |
+----+-------------+
```